# Having Issue On Replace Function

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know why I am not able to replace `&#47;` with `>` in this example

```js
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace('&#47;', ">");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<p id="demo">Change &#47;</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `&#47;` is getting translated to the real character instead (`/`). Try as follows:

```js
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace('/', ">");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<p id="demo">Change &#47;</p>
```